# F# and Unity: Set.contains fails on simple structural equality test

Tags: unity-game-engine, f#

I've run into a problem using `Set.contains` in F# running inside Unity.

(Unity does not officially support F#, but they do support including .DLLs as Plugins to provide externally-compiled code which Scripts can access. This project includes the FSharp.Core.DLL inside Unity and works well. This is the first gotcha I've run into using this approach.)

The problem is that the built-in F# structural equality support seems to fail when running under Unity under certain conditions. The identical code succeeds when run as a console application, outside Unity.

I have a sample project on github which contains a Visual Studio solution with all the pieces necessary to demonstrate the inconsistency: https://github.com/anticrisis/fsharp-unity-test

It's quite simple: when a Set is built containing a struct type, either an F# 4.1 `[<Struct>]` record, or an old style struct/vals/end type, `Set.contains` returns true when it shouldn't:

```
[<Struct>]
type V3 = {x: int; y: int; z: int} 

let testSet0 = Set.empty<V3>
let testSet1 = testSet0.Add({x = 123; y = 123; z = 123})

// fails under Unity
if testSet1.Contains {x = 0; y = 0; z = 1}
then "FAIL test: testSet1"
else "SUCCESS test: testSet1"
```

This `Contains` call should obviously return false, and it does outside of Unity. However, it returns true when run inside Unity.

Luckily, there are two main workarounds available: avoid `Set.contains` and use `Set.exists` instead. Or, use a tuple instead of a struct. Both approaches seem to avoid whatever inconsistency causes F# to fail within Unity.

The repository includes a bit more information in the README and more tests to demonstrate this problem.

Comment: Try providing a specific `IComparer` when creating the set. The standard one boxes the arguments (so the benefit of `[<Struct>]` is lost) and then relies on `IStructuralComparable`, so another thing to test is how `IStructuralComparable` works in unity.

Comment: Thank you. This is an F# Set, not a .NET Set, so it doesn't support a custom IComparer. I have tried adding custome equality and compare to the struct record, but that doesn't change this behavior. I'm still confused why this fails silently only under Unity - must be a difference in the underlying .NET libraries Unity uses, right?

Comment: Yes, `Set` does support a custom comparer, it's the first parameter of its [first constructor](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/set.fs#L518). And the default comparer it uses is not the .NET one, but the F# own custom one, which optimizes some special cases, but sadly boxes all custom types, including your record.

Comment: You're saying `LanguagePrimitives.FastGenericComparer` boxes struct types? That's surprising (I'm still new to F# obviously). Would using tuples of primitives (ints/floats) instead avoid boxing? Is there good documentation somewhere that explains this?

Comment: Struct types are new, all custom types were reference types before, so I guess they just missed this one spot when they added structs. I'm not aware of any explanation or documentation, I'm just reading the source code.

Comment: Update: I've isolated Unity out of the equation and reproduced this on the latest build of Mono 64 bit, and filed an issue with [fsharp](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/issues/823)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This unexpected behavior is caused by a bug in the Windows version of 64-bit Mono: https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/7177.

For a workaround, consider implementing `[<CustomComparison; CustomEquality>]` on any `[<Struct>]` types you define.